# XSLT create comma separated list

Tags: xml, xslt

From an incoming SAML response:

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
<saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Joe</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

Code From XSLT transform file:

```
<field name="FirstName" value="{//saml:Attribute[@Name='FirstName']/saml:AttributeValue}"/>
```

Produces this output:

```
<field name="FirstName" value="Joe"/>
```

This is working correctly. But one specified node can have multiple values, like:

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri">
<saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Joe</saml2:AttributeValue>
<saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Suzy</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

And I need the output to be:

```
<field name="FirstName" value="Joe,Suzy"/>
```

What do I need to change in my transform file to get this desired output?

**UPDATE**

I am able to now get the following output using the suggestion from 'Little Santi',  but I cannot seem to get the comma separator to work. Not sure where to add it in the document?

```
<field name="FirstName" value="JoeSuzy"/>
```

Here is the full XSLT file for reference:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <AUTHENTICATOR>
        <USERINFO>
                <field name="FirstName">
                    <xsl:attribute name="value">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//saml:Attribute[@Name='FirstName']/saml:AttributeValue"></xsl:apply-templates>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </field>    
        </USERINFO>
    </AUTHENTICATOR>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- P.S. Please post a **complete** example, not snippets taken out of their context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd re-write your field-producing template like this:

```
<field name="FirstName">
    <xsl:attribute name="value">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="saml2:Attribute[@Name='FirstName']/saml2:AttributeValue"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:attribute>
</field>
```

And then add a new template to match the attribute values:

```
<xsl:template match="saml2:AttributeValue">
<xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

(The conditional ensures that there would be a comma only between adjacent values, with no orphan commas.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm able to get it to almost work, can't seem to figure out the comma separator.

Comment: You forgot to add the new template for "saml2:AttributeValue" as I posted. (Also be careful of that saml/saml2 namespace confusion).